# Changing HttpService port using ConfigurationAdmin in Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I am using  [Apache Felix HTTP Service Jetty 2.2.0](http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi) in my project. Based on the [documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#configuration-properties) I wrote the following code to change the default service port.

```
ConfigurationAdmin configAdmin = // get ConfigurationAdmin from OSGi service registry
Configuration config = configAdmin.getConfiguration("org.apache.felix.http" ,  null);
Dictionary<String, Object> props = config.getProperties();
if(props == null)
{
  props = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
}
props.put("org.osgi.service.http.port", newport);
config.update(props);
```

As you can see I get the configuration object, update properties and call the update method.All this works fine but `HttpService` for some reason doesn't pick up the new configuration. What am I doing wrong? Between I am able to change the port by using the System property approach. But I want to be able to use `ConfigurationAdmin` to do it. 
I am running `Equinox 3.8` container

Answer (score 0):

You use the OSGi System property instead of the Felix Http config admin property ... Here is an example:

```
   "service.pid":                              "org.apache.felix.http", 
   "org.apache.felix.http.enable":             true, 
   "org.osgi.service.http.port":               8080,
   "org.apache.felix.http.debug":              true, 
   "org.apache.felix.https.debug":             true, 
   "org.apache.felix.https.enable":            true, 
   "org.osgi.service.http.port.secure":        8085,
   "org.apache.felix.https.keystore":          "@{resource:example.keystore.ks}", 
   "org.apache.felix.https.keystore.password": "@{.example.keystore}",
```

Comment: I have to do it programmatically. My application has a web interface that let's administrators to change the port. The change should be reflected on reboot. In equinox I can use config.ini file to specify these properties but that requires manual entry unless there is a OSGi specified API to update System Properties persistently.